# Encode GPS coordinates as JSON in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, json, facebook-graph-api, coordinates

Sorry if this is a very noobish question, I just could not find any answer anywhere online. I am trying to encode GPS coordinates to JSON before sending with a Facebook Graph API. I think I am doing the right thing, but keep getting an error back from the API (which I am pretty sure relates to how I am creating this structure).

Is this the right way to encode GPS coordinates in Objective C?

```
NSMutableDictionary *params1 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:3L];

NSString *latStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", Coord.latitude];
NSString *lngStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", Coord.longitude];
NSString *coordinatesString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@,%@", latStr, lngStr];

[params1 setObject:dictionaryCoordinates forKey:@"coordinates"];
```

PS: Coord is a CLLocationCoordinate2D

This is what I am getting, which seems right to me:

```
coordinates =     {
    latitude = "33.24234";
    longitude = "-120.34224";
};
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: Unrelated but why are you using 3 `stringWithFormat:` when you only need 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need actual numbers then you can do:

```
NSDictionary *coordinates = @{ @"coordinates": @{ @"latitude": @(Coord.latitude), @"longitude": @(Coord.longitude) } };
```

The `@(...)` wraps the number as an `NSNumber`.

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with the API, but I do not think, that coordinates are strings. But you send them as strings.

Use instances of `NSNumber` instead of `NSString. And you should have a view to`NSJSONParser`.

Comment: Thanks, but how would I convert the NSNumber to an NSDictionary without going through an NSString? Seems the same no?